# Calculate years of experience

Tags: r, date

I have a reproducible data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID =c(864,121,582,300,765,56,571,819,923,789,438,987,30,446,369,445),
                 city=c("del","mum","nav","pun","bang","chen","triv","vish","del","mum","bang","vish","bhop","kol","noi","gurg"),
                 name= c("xab","Lan","mun","mmc","aaf","nnhu","njam","jiha","ntha","gydbt","hytb","kula","huta","vcge","bhsue","nudj"),
                 DOJ = c("9/5/2005","8/23/2006","3/30/2006","5/29/2009","12/29/2009","6/20/2005","10/2/2010","11/15/2003","3/3/2004","4/23/2004","7/28/2003","8/27/2004","6/14/2007","3/24/2007","9/29/2009","9/4/2007"))
```

I am trying to create a function which will ask a column name of DOJ like hire date == "DOJ"
then will mutate a new column and calculate tenure in that column.

Also if the date of birth is given then mutate a new column for date of hire is greater than date of birth + 20.

I have tried using `mondf` and `difftime` but am unable to create a function for that.

Output should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
#Format date
df$DOJ <- as.Date(df$DOJ,'%m/%d/%Y')
#Compute variable
df$Tenure <- round(as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(),df$DOJ,units = 'weeks')/52.25),0)
```

Output:

```
    ID city  name        DOJ Tenure
1  864  del   xab 2005-09-05     15
2  121  mum   Lan 2006-08-23     14
3  582  nav   mun 2006-03-30     14
4  300  pun   mmc 2009-05-29     11
5  765 bang   aaf 2009-12-29     11
6   56 chen  nnhu 2005-06-20     15
7  571 triv  njam 2010-10-02     10
8  819 vish  jiha 2003-11-15     17
9  923  del  ntha 2004-03-03     16
10 789  mum gydbt 2004-04-23     16
11 438 bang  hytb 2003-07-28     17
12 987 vish  kula 2004-08-27     16
13  30 bhop  huta 2007-06-14     13
14 446  kol  vcge 2007-03-24     13
15 369  noi bhsue 2009-09-29     11
16 445 gurg  nudj 2007-09-04     13
```

Your dataset does not have date of birth but a condition like `df$NewVar <- df$Date1>Date2+20` in a new variable should produce the result you want.

Comment: i am getting error now
previously it was working

Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: @rjunkie2 Please check the structure of your data. Maybe some dates are factors or have other format.

Comment: df$NewVar <- df$Hire_date>df$DOB+20

ok will check but this is also giving error
Error in df$DOB + 20 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: > class(Hire_date)
[1] "Date"   but it saying is date format only

Comment: Your approach should work. I tested on dummy data and it works. Any of the variables is character!